# How to pass/use jstl arrayList in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, google-maps-api-3, jstl

I have a webpage with a form, where once the latitude and a longitude are entered (along with other data) and submitted, these data are saved in mongo database and at the same time a marker is place on a Google map. So , as I submit new lat/lng data, I have a new marker added on the map and so on. Now the problem is , when I switch to another page of the website and I come back to the previous page (with the map), I still have the map, but without the markers. So each time I go to the page with the map, I want the markers whose lat/lng are in the database be displayed. In other words I want to retrieve the data from the database (if there are some) and display the markers on the map each time I am on/switch to  that page.
I am facing some problems implementing a code for that and I would appreciate if someone could have a look at the following code and tell me what I am doing wrong .

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the code :

AdminWebControler.java

```
    /**
 *
 * @output ModelAndView
 * @description redirect to dashboard
 */

@RequestMapping(value = "/adminDashboard", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminPage() {
    userDao.updateLastLogin(getCurrentUser());
    final ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("iLiteList", getAllILites());
    model.setViewName("adminDashboard");
    return model;
}
```

WebcontrollerUtilities.java`

```
protected List<ILites> getAllILites(){
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

    List<ILites> ilites = mongoOperation.findAll(ILites.class, "ILites");

    System.out.println("4. Number of Ilites in the database = " + ilites.size());
    return ilites;
}
```

ILites.java

```
package mongodb.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

 @Document(collection = "ILiteDB")
 public class ILites {

private Double latitude;
private Double longitude;

/**
*

* @param longitude
* @param latitude
*/

public ILites( final Double latitude,final Double longitude) {
    super();

    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public Double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
}
```

adminDashboard.jsp (part of the jsp code (row where the map is displayed) )

```
     <div class="row">
                <h4>
                    <strong>I-Lite Network View</strong>
                </h4>
                <div>
                    <hr class="Horizontal_divider_main" />
                </div>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${not empty iLiteList}">                      
                            <div class="row" id="googleMap" style="width: 100%; height: 50%; margin-left: 3px;"> </div>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                var lat  = new array();
                                <c:forEach items="${iLiteList}" var="ilites" > 
                                    //lat.push('${ilites.latitude}');
                                    lat.push('<c:out value='${ilites.latitude}' />');
                                </c:forEach> 

                                var lng  = new array();
                                <c:forEach items="${iLiteList}" var="ilites" > 
                                    //lng.push('${ilites.longitude}');
                                    lng.push('<c:out value='${ilites.longitude}' />');
                                </c:forEach> 


                                for (i = 0; i < lat.length; i++) { 
                                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i], lng[i]);
                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: latLng,
                                    map: map,
                                    });

                                    marker.setMap(map); 

                                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

                                    content: 'Latitude: ' + location.latitude + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.longitude 
                                     });

                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                                     coordinates(map, marker, infowindow)});

                                    function coordinates(map, marker,infowindow){
                                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                                    }
                                }


                            </script>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>

            </div>
```

map.js

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(48.2188,11.6248);
var map;
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:18,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

    map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize
```

Comment: Please refer  http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsList = new Array();
<c:forEach items="${javaList}" var="javaLvar" varStatus="status"> 
   objJs = new Object();
   objJs.someProperty = ${javaLvar}; 
   jsList.push(objJs);
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand well your code. Could you please comment it using instead the variables I have use in my code?  For instance iLites , latitude and longitude ?  By the way an "ILite" in defined by its "latitude" and its "longitude" .